# Display database schema from visual studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have connected an SQL server database at my visual studio. I need to see graphically the relations between the tables at the database schema. Does anyone know if this is possible? Because I am searching for it for a long time, but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

You can create the [Database Diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171978.aspx) to see the relation between tables. You can check some more details from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171971%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the folder  Database Diagrams which mentions at the first step, does not exist for me

Comment: @JimBlum Database Diagram folder should present in every database. Make sure you are viewing inside the `VS--> Server Explorer-->Yourdatabase --> DatabaseDiagram.`

Comment: I do not have the following.

Comment: Basically, I do VS->Server Explorer->Data Connections->My Database... and it does not have anything after that..

Comment: I am not sure why it is not there? it should be there but anyway can you please try to reconnect your database from server explorer and then check.